# overflow:auto does not work with CSS3 transformed child elements. Suggested workaround?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Problem: css3 transforms applied to a child element inside a div are ignored by the browser (FF5, Chrome12, IE9) when calculating the scrollHeight and scrollWidth of the containing div's scrollbars when using "overflow: auto;".

```
<style type="text/css">
div{ width: 300px;height:500px;overflow:auto; }
div img {
-moz-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
}
</style>    
<div><img src="somelargeimage.png" /></div>
```

I have put together a small test on jsfiddle showing the undesired behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/4b9BJ/

Essentially I am trying to create a simple web based image viewer using css3 transforms for rotate and scale and would like a containing div with fixed width/height to be able to scroll to see the full content of the image it contains.

Is there an intelligent way to handle this issue, or even a rough workaround? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't expect so, one of the features of transforms is that they *don't* impact the rest of your layout.  Can you apply the transform to the containing `div` or would that ruin the effect?

Comment: No that would defeat the point, which is to be able to scroll around to see the full content of an image zoomed to where it was larger than the available screen area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an extra div to each of the transformations and by setting fixed widths for those divs and clipping overflow I manged to make them the correct size. But then I had to use position: relative and top: blah; left: blah to shift the images into the correct position.
http://jsfiddle.net/4b9BJ/7/

Comment: This looks like it worked. I attempted an inner div with adjusted fixed sizes based on the resulting images size, but did not adjust the top and left like this. Thanks!

Comment: @j0tt if you want to use javascript to dynamically zoom in and out of the image then you should be able to calculate the nessicary top: and left: values with just a few /2 or *2 as nessicary (maybe a subtraction and then a /2 in the case of rotation).

Comment: actually, you might be able to use % for the `top:` and `left:` values